# How to capture click event after a change event that displays an overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an isolated version of my code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yn183v6e/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'span', function() {
       $('#content').append('Click on span<br/>'); 
    });
    $('#input').on('change', 'input', function(e) {
        $('#content').append('Change<br/>'); 
        $('p').show();
    });
    $('body').on('click', 'p', function(e) {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
       $('#content').append('Click on body<br/>'); 
    });
});
```

There is a change event on the input box that displays an overlay. When you type in the input box, then click on the "Go" button, the change event is triggered and the click event is lost. If the overlay weren't there, the click event is captured just fine. With the overlay, the click event is lost.

I attached the click event to the body, the overlay, and the button, but the click event isn't captured.

The overlay and change event on the input box are required to enforce current business rules. How can I capture the click event?

Comment: Is delaying showing an overlay (like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rx361ssh/)) an option?

Comment: See my answer if `mousedown` event works right for your scenario

Comment: @CarlosCalla For my situation, that does work well and isn't a workaround for my situation. This is perfect.

Comment: @raina770w Personally, this doesn't work for my situation. However, when I changed the delay to 1 (instead of 100) it works perfectly, and I would have used as a workaround had I been able to implement it in our current front-end architecture.

Comment: Actually it is a correct way to order your events. There are no problems with this.

Comment: why not use ajaxStart to show overlay either by custom event or directly using `show()`

Comment: @CarlosCalla I was agreeing that it is correct :)

Comment: @Josh :O haha sorry I thought It didn't fit your requirements because you didn't mark it as the solution to your question.

Comment: Not competing with Carlos's correct answer, just offering another approach because I was working on it before I know it was over with and didnt want to waste the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mousedown` event to get it triggered before the `change` event on `input`

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/yn183v6e/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('mousedown', 'span', function() { // Changed click event for mousedown event
       $('#content').append('Click on span<br/>'); 
    });
    $('#input').on('change', 'input', function(e) {
        $('#content').append('Change<br/>'); 
        $('p').show();
        debugger;
    });
    $('body').on('click', 'p', function(e) {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
       $('#content').append('Click on body<br/>'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `click` event, but the  allmighty `<p>` that you're placing on the `change` event.

Since the `change` is being fired first, on the blur of the input, the `p` is placed above everything, and your `span` is never reached by the click...

The body click is fired because `<p>` is a part of the body anyway...

Remove the `$('p').show();` and see: http://jsfiddle.net/yn183v6e/6/

Comment: That's intentional. On each change event of our input, there is an overlay (which is the p in this case) that displays because there is an ajax call happening underneath and the overlay is actually a loading screen. I have click events on the body, the overlay, and the span, but the click event doesn't reach any of them.

Comment: "Click on body" is triggered normally for me

Comment: Not when you type in the input box, then try and click "Go".

Comment: Yes, it does for me... It triggers `Change`, then `Click on the body`

Comment: He wants the `Click on span`